# AppleScript simulate user keyboard input

Tags: macos, applescript

First, I change the system input method to the method I want.(Some chinese input method). 
What I am trying to do is read some letters from one `txt` file,  and then use the input method to "translate" these letters to the Chinese words and write them to a new file. Which simulate the user input some words. 
However, I found that when the script run a long time (10 or 20 min), the script will stop. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post your code. However, you can change the period in which a script times out with:

```
with timeout of 120 seconds
    -- your code goes here
end timeout
```

Comment: It's very strange that on some mac it will run correctly taken 80% chance, but on some, it will stop 100%